# How can I tell the depth of a git repository?

Tags: git

A script I am debugging is supposed to use `--depth 1` when cloning a git repository in order to avoid downloading all its history. However, I suspect it might be buggy and that it is actually performing a full clone.

How can I inspect the resulting repository to determine if it was cloned with `--depth 1` or not?

Comment: Have you tried just doing `git log`?  Wouldn't this show what the available history is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you made a shallow clone `--depth 1` use

```
git rev-list --count --all
```

if it outputs `1` you only have 1 commit in the object database.

Does the script use the `--no-single-branch` option? 
This would explain why git fetches multiple commits (each for every branch or tag)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

If the contents of `.git/shallow` are the same as `git rev-parse HEAD`, the depth is 1.

Comment: `.git/shallow` has 6 lines, one of which is the same as `git rev-parse HEAD`. Could this have to do with the fact that this repository has submodules?